# Three Line Break chart using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need to create interactive "Three Line Break chart". It is a type of chart that mainly used in financial/stock analysis.

I downloaded [ASP.NET chart control samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) from msdn and played around with the "Three line break chart" type that included in the package. It looks great but it is not interactive (chart gennerated is an image ) so I can not just use it.

So, I think I need to use Silverlight, I am wondering anyone knows if there is any free Silverlight chart control package that provides this type of chart out of box?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) provides some charting controls. Samples can be watch [here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html). An other good library that provides chart ist [visifire](http://visifire.com/). But you need a licence if you want to use it commercial.

Comment: Neither Silverlight Toolkit or Visifire provide a Three Line Break Chart.

Comment: That's what I found too. I am going to try build one myself. Thanks.